# Particular bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I usually add bibliography to my tex files by adding the lines:

```
\bibliographystyle{ChemEurJ}
\bibliography{filename}
```

where 'ChemEurJ' is the style I usually use for the appearance of my bibliography and 'filename' is the .bib file in which I have all the articles, etc. that I want to cite.

Coming to the problem, does anybody know if there exists a bibliography style that would give the following as result?

> L. Elisa, F. Baldini, A. Giannetti, C. Trono and T. Carofiglio, Solid-supported
>   Zn(II) porphyrin tweezers as optical sensors for diamines, *Chem. Comm.* **2010**,
>   *46*, 3678

I looked for it for a while and I couldn't find it. On the other hand there are so many bibliography styles that I could have missed it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Isn't that just the _Angewandte_ style with article titles? If so, perhaps the easiest way is to use (my) `rsc` bundle, which has an `angew` style and a control system for including titles.

Comment: Looking a bit more, I see that this is a bit of a mix: you've got 'and' in the author list (like the RSC style), but no comma after the journal title. I can't think of a journal that does this: can you give us a clue?

Comment: Thanks Joseph for the comment. Unfortunately I don't know which journal does it like this. I need to write a report and the bibliography style I have to use must strictly be this one.

Comment: What I'm suspicious of is that it's almost always the case that you are expected to follow some publishers style, so I wonder if it's meant to be subtly different. Probably the easiest way to get what you want is to use `biblatex`: is that OK? If so, it's a relatively minor adjustment to one of the standard styles.

Comment: I ended up generating my own style (i.e. a `bst` file) using the `custom-bib` package following this tutorial `http://www-hep.colorado.edu/~jcumalat/4610_fall_10/bibtex_guide.pdf`. I didn't find it too bad. `biblatex` seems the ultimate solution for such problems, even though in this case `custom-bib` provided me a relatively quick solution.